# Why do ternary operator and if statement return different results?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-7.1

In the following example, I'm returning a `DateTimeOffset?` using the [`default` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)

```cs
var a = ConvertToDateTimeOffsetA(null); // 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00
var b = ConvertToDateTimeOffsetB(null); // null

private static DateTimeOffset? ConvertToDateTimeOffsetA(DateTime? date)
{
    return date != null
        ? new DateTimeOffset(date.Value, TimeSpan.Zero)
        : default;
}
private static DateTimeOffset? ConvertToDateTimeOffsetB(DateTime? date)
{
    if (date != null) 
        return new DateTimeOffset(date.Value, TimeSpan.Zero);
    return default;
}
```

Why is there a difference between the returned output in the ternary compared to the if statement?

My guess would be the ternary first coerces the type to `DateTimeOffset` and then inline converts back to `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`, but I'm not quite sure why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the ternary version, it is interpreting your `default` as `default(DateTimeOffset)`, the other output expression type in the conditional. Then it is interpreting the ternary *as a whole* as a nullable, which will never be null.

In the second case, your return is using `default(DateTimeOffset?)`, from the declared return type.

In this case, you may want to use an explicit type in the `default` expression, or: just use the second form *and add a comment* (and ideally a unit test), so nobody "fixes" it in the future.

Comment: ahhh - thanks Marc!